# How to add to an array stored as Any in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, any

I have a member which out of necessity is of type `Any`:

```
var type: MyValueType
var value: Any!
```

One of the possible types for value is `Array< Int >`
How can I add to the array that is stored in value?

I tried casting, but the result of a cast is considered a let constant.

Using this:

```
if var arr = (value as! Array<Int>) { ... }
```

does not work either because arr is then a *copy* of the array, not the array itself.

I could, of course, assign `arr` to `value` again but does that not create unnecessary copying?

Comment: I believe it is not possible to typecast Any to a mutable version of [Int] and thus you need to do reassign the value after append.

Comment: The *unnecessary copying* is actually pretty fast thanks to the *copy-on-write* policy used by Swift arrays. It’s a O(1) space/time operation.

Comment: Oh well, dawn the aesthetics, I will simply create a second 'value' i.e. 'arrayValue' that is to be used for array's then...
Thanks everybody!

Comment: And, in fact, the unnecessary copying might be optimised out in a release build.

Answer (score 2):

You can optional bind the array to a temporary variable, make the mutation and assign the temporary variable back for example

```
var value : Any!

value = [1, 2, 3]

if var intArray = value as? [Int] {
    intArray.append(4)
    value = intArray
}
```

The *unnecessary copying* is necessary in this case.

An alternative could be a protocol based solution. Everything is better than `Any`.